# Mythbuntu-default settings not installing: 12.04 LTS

Tags: 12.04, mythbuntu

I was just installing some rather nice desktop environments ( Gnome, Lubuntu, Xubuntu, etc...)
when I decided, you know what? Mythbuntu sounds awesome! I'll get that too. Now whenever I log on I get crash report, an internal error, system error, and update manger is telling me "Package system broken" I don't need Mythbuntu but I do enjoy it, is there a quick and easy removal, or fix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you log into the system using a CLI? If so, you could remove it from there or at least see detailed information about the error which *should* point us in the right direction.

Comment: So sorry, I'm still fairly new to Ubuntu, I think this is my 6th day of serious use. I can log in with a CLI, however where should I go from there?

Comment: Try running "sudo apt-get check" <- this will check from packages with broken dependencies.

Comment: `Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 mythbuntu-desktop : Depends: mythbuntu-default-settings but it is not installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.`

Comment: Gotta love Linux error messages :) Run "sudo apt-get check -f" (fair warning, I don't remember the exact line...)

Comment: `Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done`

Comment: Now try rebooting, from the CLI I believe it's `shutdown -r 0` <- that's a zero at the end.

Comment: Done that. Erm, errors still popping up, normal?

Comment: Same errors? You may want to removing Mythbuntu.

Comment: Is there a painless way to do that?

Comment: To be honest, I'm not sure. How did you install it?

Comment: `snackadoodlepop@snackadoodlepop-desktop:~$ sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install mythbuntu-desktop`

Comment: In that case you should be able to uninstall it using `sudo apt-get remove mythbuntu-desktop`

Comment: It looks to be working, thank you SO much man, this is life saving, I did not want to reinstall Ubuntu, and I can't live with those error messages. I gave you as much rep as I could. Great answer, and thank you for sticking with me for each step.

Comment: You're very welcome, I'm just glad I could help :)